# Why are Mac Catalyst compilation warnings caused by iOS deployment target and not macOS deployment target?

Tags: ios, xcode, mac-catalyst

I'm trying to understand why when compiling the macCatalyst version of an iOS app, I am getting errors about APIs only being available on macCatalyst 14.0 or newer when I have selected a macOS deployment target of macOS 13.0 (which is macCatalyst 16.0 I believe). These errors appear if the iOS deployment target is set to anything less than iOS 14.0.

It seems to me that the macOS deployment target should be used when compiling the macCatalyst version of the app, not the iOS deployment target.

This issue is easily replicated. Use Xcode to create a new iOS app project. Set the iOS deployment target to iOS 13.0. On the target's General tab, delete the "Mac (Designed for iPad)" destination and then add the "Mac (Mac Catalyst)" destination. In the build settings choose a "macOS deployment target" of macOS 13.0.

Pull up the AppDelegate class and add a reference to `AVAuthorizationStatus` in one of the delegate methods. This API is available for iOS 7.0+, macOS 10.14+, and Mac Catalyst 14.0+.

For example (Objective-C):

```objectivec
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    AVAuthorizationStatus status;

    return YES;
}
```

Or in Swift:

```swift
import AVFoundation

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    var status: AVAuthorizationStatus

    return true
}
```

Now select the "My Mac (Mac Catalyst)" as the build destination and you will see the warning (or error)

> 'AVAuthorizationStatus' is only available in Mac Catalyst 14.0 or newer

If you then change the iOS deployment target from iOS 13.0 to iOS 14.0 or later then the issue goes away. But why? Why isn't the macOS deployment target relevant here? I'm trying to build for macOS 13.0 or later. The chosen API *is* available for macOS 13.0 (Mac Catalyst 16.0). This makes no sense to me.

And yes, I have an app that needs to support versions of iOS earlier than iOS 14.0, in addition to macOS 13.0 or later. I have over 100 of these warnings in my real project so I can't just deal with a warning or two.

All of my tests are with Xcode 14.3 on macOS 13.2.1.